# Backbone - json data not displayed in browser but rendering in console

Tags: json, backbone.js

I am able to see the json data in console, but not displayed in the html. I am not sure what change must be done to make it render in the browser.
Here is my code.

**Model.js**

```
var agent = Backbone.Model.extend({ 

});

var agentList = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
  model: agent,
  url: 'data/agents.json',
});
```

**View.js**

```
var agentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.container', 

  initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template( tpl.get('agentList'));
  },   

  render: function() {      
    var agents = new agentList();
    agents.fetch({
      success: function(agents) {
        console.log(agents.toJSON());
      }
    });
    this.$el.html(this.template({ AgentsList: agents.toJSON()}))
  },
});
```

**HTML**

```
  <% _.each(AgentsList, function(item) { %>           
  <tr>
  <td>data</td>
  <td><%= item.name%></td>
  <td><%= item.gender%></td>
  <td><%= item.birthYear%></td>
  <td><%= item.skills%></td>
  </tr>          
  <% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't render the view in the callback, and therefore you won't have anything to show.

Besides, getting the list of agents inside the render function is definitely not something to do if you want to respect MVC principles. You should have something like:

```
var agentCol = new AgentList();
var agentView = new AgentListView({collection: agentCol});

agentCol.fetch({
  success: function() {
    agentView.render();
  }
});
```

and your AgentListView should look like

```
var AgentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.container',

  initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template(tpl.get('agentList'));
  },   

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({ agents: this.collection.toJSON()}));
  },
});
```

(I took the liberty to rename some variables to match naming conventions)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried out this. but same result. no data displayed in browser

Comment: Can you give a bit more details? Any error in the console? Did you check if the AJAX response was correct? Did you put a few breakpoints to check _if_ render() is called _after_ fetch()?

Comment: WoW! great.. Thank you very much Emmanuel. It worked!. The mistake i made was, instead of the collection i put the collection name (agents - in my case).

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe because the time when the `$el` update code runs the `agents` collection is not loaded (fetched) yet.

May be you can update your render method with the code below, so that the `$el` shall be updated only when the collection fetch is returned from the server.

```
render: function() {
  var $this = this;
  var agents = new agentList();
  agents.fetch({
    success: function(agents) {
      console.log(agents.toJSON());
      $this.$el.html($this.template({ AgentsList: agents.toJSON() }));
    }
  });
}
```

Or an an alternative you can listen to the collection event (`reset` maybe) which fires whenever the data is fetched from the remote data source - json file in this case.

In that case the view code could be,

```
var agentListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '.container', 

  initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template( tpl.get('agentList'));
    this.collection = new agentList();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.addAgentsToDom);
  },   

  render: function() {      
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: function(agents) {
        console.log(agents.toJSON());
      }
    });
  },

  addAgentsToDom: function(collection, options) {  // please name the method whatever you want :)
    this.$el.html(this.template({ AgentsList: this.collection.toJSON() }));
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried both solution. The first one shows the below error in console, "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'template'". The second one, no error but again the data not loaded. Kindly help me to resolve this..

Comment: again, this error. "Uncaught ReferenceError: $this is not defined ".

Comment: Actually in first approach we're just storing the view reference `this` into `$this` to be used in the callback, because in success callback, `this` doesn't refer to the view. Ideally it should work, no clue why isn't it working :(. In the second approach, could you please put a debugger or a console.log in `addAgentsToDom` method and see what is the value of `this.collection` there ?

Comment: That is not even calling that funcion, I tried giving alert. its not working.